# Find input whose name attribute value has [somedigit] in it

Tags: jquery, selector, string-matching

I've got several divs inside which are inputs like this:

```
<div class="executor">
   <input type="hidden" name="Task.Executors[0].Id"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="Task.Executors[0].Name"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="Task.Executors[0].JobTitle"/>
</div>
<div class="executor">
   <input type="hidden" name="Task.Executors[1].Id"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="Task.Executors[2].Name"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="Task.Executors[3].JobTitle"/>
</div>
```

I need a selector that does this: Find those inputs whose name contains `Executors[somedigit]`. That `somedigit` part is what makes it hard for me. Do I need regex for this?

EDIT: I seem to have missed a very important part. I need to change `Executors[somedigit]` to something like `Executors[2]`. So I need something that will help me replace `somedigit` with another one.

EDIT2: Why I need this. Suppose there are 100 of such divs. Normally the last div is going to contain the hidden inputs whose name contains `Task.Executors[99]`. Now, let's say the 87'th div gets removed. Now there are 99 divs and now the inputs inside the last div must have their names changed from `Task.Executors[99]` to `Task.Executors[98]`. I need those indexes to be correct so that my model is a valid model.

Comment: You can use attribute contains selector `$('[name*="Executor["]')`

Comment: you mean you want a specific selection to Executor[2] only at a time

Comment: I'm going to iterate inside divs that have class "executor". At each iteration I need to replace the `somedigit` part with the current iteration index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use attribute contains selector along with concatenation of required number:

```
var somenum = 2;
$('[name*="Executor['+ somenum  +']"]')
```

**DEMO:**

```js
$(function(){
var somenum = "0";
$('[name*="Executor['+ somenum  +']"]').val('abv')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="executor">
   <input type="text" name="Task.Executor[0].Id"/>
   <input type="text" name="Task.Executor[0].Name"/>
   <input type="text" name="Task.Executor[0].JobTitle"/>
</div>
<div class="executor">
   <input type="text" name="Task.Executor[1].Id"/>
   <input type="text" name="Task.Executor[2].Name"/>
   <input type="text" name="Task.Executor[3].JobTitle"/>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know the value of `somenum` beforehands.

Comment: not clear. can you elaborate. what elements you want to target

Comment: I've added more exaplanation to my question. Please see the EDIT2

Comment: @MikayilAbdullayev: you can use ``$('.executor .hidden:first-child').attr('name',function(){return "Task.Executors["+ $(this).closest('.executor').index() + "].Id"})`` for setting ids

Answer (score 0):

You can use css selector `$("[name^='Task.Executor']")` for selecting all elements with name starting with Task.Executor.

for more selectors you can check : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp